# How to reinstall nginx if I deleted /etc/nginx folder (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to reinstall nginx, but I have this

```
nginx -t

nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()    
"/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2015/01/25 16:18:01 [emerg] 1400#0: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"   
failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How to install and start nginx if I removed all the nginx folders?

Comment: Thanks! I your questions saves me weekends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo aptitude purge nginx && sudo aptitude install nginx
```

This code will remove and reinstall Nginx

Comment: I tried to do it, but it doesn't work. I tried autoremove as well.

Comment: The message in the first post

Comment: I solved the problem. There were several packages, including nginx-core and nginx-common. I removed them manually and it works.

Comment: @Curiosity how did you fix this issue , I did the same thing not when I try to renistall I get the following error awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: You should remove all the config files (you have to do it with sudo aptitude purge <your package name>). I had several different packages including nginx-core and nginx-common. So purge nginx-core should help you. Try to find all the installed packages and remove it all.

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 18 

Comment: @Curiosity if reinstalling nginx-core and nginx-common is the solution why don't you accept the other answer by Ilko?

Comment: This solution did not removed nginx from my system. The solution proposed by Ilko is much more complete.

Answer (score 87):

Login as **root** or:

```
sudo su -
```

Then uninstall nginx:

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
```

And then install it:

```
apt-get install nginx
```

The other way is to run sudo command with `-H`:

```
sudo -H apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full  
sudo -H apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Also you can try:
    sudo -H apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
 
    sudo -H apt-get install nginx

Comment: Thanks., It's working. you saved mine time. +1

Answer (score 25):

```
apt-get --purge remove nginx-*
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Use this to purge all the extra packages, such as nginx-core, before reinstalling. Works perfectly for getting rid of all the extra bits that aptitude still thought were around.